# PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP Error in QNX 7

Tags: linux, pthreads, qnx

I am porting code from Linux to QNX 7. PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP is used in many places in my code. In Linux, this is defined in pthread.h. In QNX, I am unable to find where this is defined. Hence throwing error:
"PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP' undeclared here (not in a function)".

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/include/pthread.h:
# ifdef __USE_GNU
#  define PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP \
  { { 0, 0, 0, 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP, __PTHREAD_SPINS, { 0, 0 } } }
```

Try to define __USE_GNU before including pthread:

```
#define __USE_GNU
#include <pthread.h>
```

Comment: #define _GNU_SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

Although recursive mutexes are standardised in POSIX, the standard doesn't specify a static initialiser for them (`PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` is a glibc extension).

This means to be portable, you need to initialise your recursive mutexes manually with `pthread_mutex_init()`:

```
int init_recursive_mutex(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    int r;

    r = pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    if (r != 0)
        return r;

    r = pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

    if (r == 0)
        r = pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &attr);

    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    return r;
}
```

For the mutexes which you are statically initialising, you can instead initialise them with a function like the above called at the start of `main()` for each mutex.